# Javascript Objects enumeration

Tags: javascript

What's the difference of putting/changing `"property"` to `this[property]` in console, I believe both refer to the same expression but the latter gives me [object, Object] when I call the function.

```
var rockSpearguns = {
    Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand"},
    Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder"},
    Javelinjet: {barbs: 4, weight: 12, heft: "waist"},
    Firefork: {barbs: 6, weight: 8, heft: "overhand"},
    "The Impaler": {barbs: 1, weight: 30, heft: "chest"}
};

rockSpearguns["listGuns"] = function(){
    for (var property in this) {
        if(this[property]["heft"]!==undefined){
            console.log("Behold! " + this[property] + ", with " +
            this[property]["heft"] + " heft!");
        }
    }
}

rockSpearguns["listGuns"]();
```

Comment: Are you asking what is the difference between `this["property"]` and `this[property]`???

Comment: nope, the property and this[property] in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`property` will be the keys of the object beign looped (`"Sharpshooter"`, `"Pokepistol"`, ...) which are already strings.

`this[property]` will be the values of the object which are all objects. When concatinating an object with a string the object is cast into a string by calling its function `toString`. So:

```
var obj = {};
var string = "Hello. I'm " + obj;
```

is the same as:

```
var obj = {};
var string = "Hello. I'm " + obj.toString();
```

`obj.toString()` in this case will return `"[object Object]"`.

About bracket and dot notation, here is a the docs on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 1):

When you access `this` in console or within a simple script, it refers to `window`, so is the same as accessing variable, which is inside the `window` scope.

```
var a = 123; // variable `a` is bound to `window`
console.log(a); // 123
console.log(window.a); // 123
console.log(this.a); // 123
```

But when you are inside a function or object, `this` refers to its own context:

```
function test () {
    this.a = 123;
    console.log(a); // 123
    console.log(this.a); // 123
    console.log(this); // test {a: 123}
}

new test(); // to create new context for this function, we need to call `new`, otherwise it will also be `window`

console.log(typeof a); // undefined
console.log(this.a); // undefined
console.log(this); // window
```

More about this: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: but they are just the same, except in the console, isn't it?

Comment: well it can be changed via `bind` method, but generaly when you are not within a function or object, `this` will refer to `window`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later.

Comment: I edited my answer with example of `this` inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `for` loop the `this` will be `rockSpearGuns` object. In this case the `this[property]` will refer for example the `Firefork` object. You need to use `property` instead of `this[property]`.

Try this:

```js
var rockSpearguns = {
  Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand"},
  Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder"},
  Javelinjet: {barbs: 4, weight: 12, heft: "waist"},
  Firefork: {barbs: 6, weight: 8, heft: "overhand"},
  "The Impaler": {barbs: 1, weight: 30, heft: "chest"}
};
    
rockSpearguns["listGuns"]=function(){
  for (var property in this) {
    if(this[property]["heft"]!==undefined){
      console.log("Behold! " + property + ", with " +
      this[property]["heft"] + " heft!");
    }
  }
}
    
rockSpearguns["listGuns"]();
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it isn't a for loop but a for in loop :) . Also why is it always required to use a combination of bracket and a dot notation in accessing object and object properties when you try to debug it in sites like JS Bin?

Comment: Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors
If you use a variable to identify a property of object then you need to use brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Let's dissect it bit by bit:

`rockSpearguns["listGuns"]()` call is another way of saying:
rockSpearguns.listGuns();
This means the context of "this" is set to rockSpearguns object(at the call site).

When JS tries to evaluate this[property] value, it sees that value of this object is bound to rockSpearguns and "property" is enumerated value of the object property which is string(due to for-in loop). However, this[property] simply means this.property(dot notation).
In this case this.property is an object(Sharpshooter etc.)
Now when we are trying to concatenate strings, Sharpshooter object needs to be converted to string by calling toString() method which gives back [object, Object].